# What is the use of TestNG in Selenium Webdriver Hybrid Framework?

Tags: excel, selenium, frameworks, testng, hybrid

Suppose I am running scripts by reading data(including runmode) from an XLS and storing the results also in a new copy of the XLS, what exactly would be the role of TestNG in the framework? Please help.. Thanks in Advance!!

Rajesh

Comment: Kindly read here TestNG benefits : http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/testng-introduction/

Answer (score 1):

TestNG is not just to manage the way you read your input parameters/data etc. It actually does a lot more. Try to answer these questions -
- How do you invoke some method always on a Class load ?
- How do you invoke some method before/after each method within your test ?
- How do you tell which is your test ?
- How to generate an HTML based report based on the log statements you have ?

The answer to above queries (if TestNG was not there) would have been really complex and would require quite some coding experience.
As suggested earlier, please read the info about TestNG and how it can be efficiently utilized and then again try to answer the above questions in this post.

Comment: Hi Dharam, thanks for quick reply but i have some doubts as I am new to this.. 1)How do you invoke some method always on a Class load ? -- Not sure what you meant by this 2)How do you invoke some method before/after each method within your test ? -- I have this defined in XLS, i mean once I run the driver script, every step is read from XLS 3)How do you tell which is your test ? - Its in XLS 4)How to generate an HTML based report based on the log statements you have ? -- would store the results in XLS again.. I am not really able to understand the benefits of TestNG... pls help

Comment: Again, I would want you to read through the basics of TestNG that covers annotations like `@BeforeClass, @BeforeMethod, @AfterTest, @AfterMethod, @DataProvider` etc. Its perfectly alright that you are interested in XLS based reports, you may ignore the HTML reports. 

Please go through the following 2 links that clearly explains the benefits -

http://blog.varunin.com/2010/04/what-is-testng-and-whats-difference.html
http://www.guru99.com/all-about-testng-and-selenium.html

Even the link by @HelpingHands is good.

Whether to use or not to use TestNG solely depends upon you.

Comment: At present your goal may just be to automate a scenario and run it from XLS, but think from a long term perspective of the automation code and the scenarios/execution cycles that might exponentially increase over time.

Comment: Thanks Dharam, I have some better understanding now but need to explore more thanks once again:)